# Physical interpretation of the constant coefficient appearing in solution to the Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space, superposition, born-rule

The product solution to the Schrodinger's equation is 
$$\Psi_{n} \left ( x,t \right )=\psi\left ( x \right )\phi\left ( t \right )$$

By superposition, the solution becomes

$$\Psi \left ( x,t \right )=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}  \psi_{n} \left ( x \right )\phi_{n} \left ( t \right )$$

In the book "Introduction to Quantum Mechanics" by Griffiths, the author hand waved about the constant coefficient $C_n$ being the amount of $\psi_{n}$ that is contained within $\Psi$, but I'm not too sure if I am comfortable with this explanation, as it isn't very rigorous. Is there a better (and obviously more improved explanation) way to see what role that constant coefficient plays in the quantum system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a much more general rule that works for any inner product space. When you describe a vector $v$ in terms of other "basis" vectors $v_n$, the sum can be written out as:
$$v=\sum_n (v_n, v) v_n$$
Where the bracketed value is the inner product, or "how much" of $v_n$ is in $v $. This relationship holds for much more general objects than just vectors in $\mathbb {R}^n$.

In fact, if one views the set of continuous functions as a vector space,  and one defines the inner product as:
$$(g (x),f(x))=\int_0^\pi f (x)g(x)dx $$
And the basis vectors as $\sin (nx),\cos (nx) $, the relationship above becomes the definition of the Fourier series, and the coefficients the amount of a certain frequency within a function.

A similar idea is going on here withe the wave functions  $\Psi_n $ replacing the sines and cosines.

Comment: Just to be precise, for your decomposition to work the basis needs to be orthomormal. But in QM we pretty much always use those anyway.

Comment: @Javier - Of course. I didn't want to get into all the gory details.